# How to send POST data with code in an android webview

Tags: android, http, post, authentication, webview

I have an android application that consists of a `WebWiew` and I need to login to a site automatically using code. I've tried using `postUrl()` and it seems to work... but only on some sites.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
public class webviewActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        String postData = "login_email=myEmail@gmail.com&login_password=myPassword";
        webview.postUrl("https://www.dropbox.com/login", EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "utf-8"));
    }
}
```

This Works **great** for dropbox.com, but other sites like google.com, facebook.com, etc. just load the login page or give an error (google.com gives an error saying I need to enable cookies).

Right now I'm just going the post data by hand; looking at the login form for the site and putting the name/value fields in the postData in my code. On sites like google, the login form has many hidden fields and I've been adding those to the postData also.

If anyone could give me any idea of something I'm doing wrong please let me know, I'm pretty confused about this.

Comment: can we check this in Postman ??? if yes how to do so ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try replacing `"utf-8"` (in the 2nd param) with `"BASE64"`.

Comment: Hi an00b. Thanks for the answer! I believe I have tried this with no luck. I'm no longer working on this specific problem, I decided to go a separate route. I'll vote you up anyway, because I really appreciate the answer.

Comment: "BASE64" is no character set, so this may work (depending on the postData) but it may as well fail. The correct way is to encode the postData to be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" encoded, which can be done with URLEncoder.encode(postData, "UTF-8");

Comment: raudi can u put an answer with a snippet useing  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Answer (score 11):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    WebView webView = new WebView(this);

    setContentView(webView);

    String url = "http://example.com/somepage.php";
    String postData = "postvar=value&postvar2=value2";

    webView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "base64"));
}
```

Comment: I read the source code of EncodingUtils.java in Android [HERE](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4/org/apache/http/util/EncodingUtils.java#95)
`EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "base64")` as same as `postData.getBytes()`.  
 Just use `postData.getBytes()` instead of EncodingUtils.  
(If you need migrate to Android M (API 23) with no EncodingUtils)

Comment: You saved my day dude.

Answer (score 2):

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

String url="http://www.example.org/login";

String postData=
                "username="+URLEncoder.encode("abc","UTF8")+
                "&password="+URLEncoder.encode("***", "UTF-8");

myWebView.postUrl(url,postData.getBytes());
```

Comment: Where should we mention the "x-www-form-urlencoded" format?