# Set/Change changing the WebView user agent in Android

Tags: android, android-webview, user-agent

I have a website which should supposedly only using WebView in my app, otherwise my website redirects the user to a page from where he can download my App.

So, how can I change this UA in WebView?

Also, what are the possible issues which can arise from this?

Comment: Did you try [`myWebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("custom user agent")`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47166980/1518921)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send any POST parameter to your website in your app. Otherwise your website can determines that is calling from other browsers.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586564/how-to-send-post-data-with-code-in-an-android-webview) is a sample may help you.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [**`setUserAgent`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUserAgentString(java.lang.String)) from `android.webkit.WebSettings`, simple example:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

WebSettings myWebSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
myWebSettings.setUserAgentString("Foo/Bar"); # Set your custom user-agent
```

> Also, what are the possible issues which can arise from this?

Depends on what you did, `userAgent` is not "perfect", but was created for this purpose, identify the browser.