# Andorid Webview How to POST data to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: android, post, webview, urlencode

I have a Webview In that I am loading web with Query string perimeters
like

```
String url = map.get("utype") + map.get("sid") + "/login/login.php?"+"&"+"strid" + "=" + map.get("strid")+"&"+"appmod" + "=" + map.get("appmod")+"&" +"ttype" + "=" + map.get("ttype")+"&" +"payp" + "=" + map.get("payp");
```

I am loading that Query string in webview

```
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

So Now Insted of using Query string I want to POST Parameters to **`x-www-form-urlencoded`**

These are my Parameters

```
strid = map.get("strid");
appmod = map.get("appmod");
ttype = map.get("ttype");
payp = map.get("payp");
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7586564/5010291) but its not Working

can any one help me on this..

I want to POST data to **`x-www-form-urlencoded`** in Web-view

After posting I it will load my Web-server(website).

**Update**

I have Given these values for post

```
String postData="strid="+URLEncoder.encode(map.get("strid"), "UTF-8")+
"&appmod="+URLEncoder.encode(map.get("appmod"), "UTF-8")+
"&ttype="+URLEncoder.encode(map.get("ttype"), "UTF-8")+
"&payp="+URLEncoder.encode(map.get("payp"), "UTF-8");
```

Now after Adding The Details I have given this to at URL

```
webView.postUrl(url,postData.getBytes());
```

But still Its not working

can anyone suggest me whats wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `webView.postUrl(url, encodedData);`

Values must be encoded with **URLEncoder.encode(postData, "UTF-8")** or **"BASE64"** depends on backend.

If its not working make sure you have url in correct format. You can also share it to here without exposing your values if you are not sure.

Comment: Thanks for Response user@Emre Aktürk ,, But How Ever  I already Tried And I have Given Reference link also... I am using `webView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "UTF-8"));`

Comment: Did you solve this issue @Don'tBenegative ? I am stuck now.