# How to load this html and send value to post method in webview android

Tags: android, webview

I want to load this following html data and pass email and password to this $credential using post method,I don't know how to load this data in webview android ,any idea please share me,the code are

```
$return_to = "https://exmaple.support.com/support/index.php?/Base/User/Login";
  echo "<html><body>";
  echo "<form action=\"$return_to\" id=\"kRedir\" method=\"post\">";
  foreach ($credentials as $key => $value) {
       echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"$key\" name=\"$key\" value=\"$value\" /> ";
  }
  echo "</form>";
  echo "<sc ript>document.forms[0].submit();</sc ript>";
  echo "</body></html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

May be, you just need to use `postUrl` method of UIWebView.
You can look answers about using of it here [How to send POST data with code in an android webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586564/how-to-send-post-data-with-code-in-an-android-webview/46951154)

P.S. Don't forget about encoding of parameters.

Comment: but ,they have php file is base url ,but i dont have  any file ,how to do this,please my above code